# Simplificar/Optimizar FOR

Tags: javascript, bucles

Como puedo hacer para simplificar el segundo *for*, es decir, quisiera mejorarlo/optimizarlo, veo que es repetitivo pero no entiendo como mejorarlo:

```
var book =[ {
    title: "The Giver",
    stars: 4,
    author: "Manuel G. H.",
    color: color(255, 183, 0)
    },
    {
    title: "Adventures",
    stars: 5,
    author: "Humberto B.B",
    color: color(152, 234, 245)
    },
    {
    title: "Rock N Roll",
    stars: 2,
    author: "Buitrago M.H",
    color: color(0, 255, 0)
    }];

//Soporte para libros
fill(173, 117, 33);
rect(0, 120, width, 10);

for ( var books = 0 ; books < book.length ; books++){

    fill(book[books].color);
    rect(10 + books * 100, 20, 90, 100);

    fill(0, 0, 0);
    text(book[books].title, 23 + books * 100, 29, 70, 100);
    text(book[books].author, 23 + books * 100, 69, 70, 100);    
}

for (var i = 0; i < book[books].stars ; i++) {

            var space = 100;

            if(book[books].stars <= 4){
                image(getImage("cute/Star"), 12 + i * 17 , 90, 20, 30);
                espacio += 100;
            }
            if(book[books].stars <= 5){
                image(getImage("cute/Star"), 12 + space + i * 17, 90, 20, 30);

            }
            if(book[books].stars <= 2){
                image(getImage("cute/Star"), 12 + spcae + i * 17, 90, 20, 30);
            }        
}
```

Comment: Describe que es lo que quieres que tu código haga. Es conveniente que sigas el [tour] y leas [ask] para conocer algunos elementos básicos del funcionamiento de este sitio.

Comment: Tienes un error corrige `spacio += 100` por `space += 100`

Comment: tienes otro error corrige `spcae` por `space` ese código no esta en producción.

Answer (score 1):

En el código que has puesto hay varios errores, independientemente de lo que quieras hacer, que aunque se intuye no está muy claro.

1) Estás usando un nombre de variable en singular `book` para referirte a algo que lo más normal es que contenga varias cosas. Sería mejor nombrarla `books`.

2) En el primer bucle, la variable índice de llama `books`, lo que de nuevo lleva a confusión. Usa lo que todo el mundo, `i` o como mucho `book_idx`. Cada variable tiene que describir lo que contiene.

3) En el segundo bucle estás utilizando la variable `books` que está fuera de ámbito, ya que la declaraste en la parte de inicialización del `for` anterior. Y aunque siguiese presente en el ámbito actual, tendría valor `3` (el que hace que el bucle anterior finalice), por lo que `book[books]` te dará error de índice fuera de rango. Tal vez quieras anidar el segundo bucle dentro del primero.

Comment: Si eso veo, tengo varios errores de base... voy a probar lo de anidar y veremos que tal se mueve.  Gracias!!

Comment: Hola @ManuelSZ18, ¿te funcionó?